# Add class by to anchor by checking the match with current title?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a navigation menu like:

```
<div class="my_menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://localhost/en/about-us">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost/en/contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I am trying to write a function to add some active class to the menu when it matches with page url.

```
$(".top_navigation li a").filter(function() {
    alert($(this).href);
    alert($(location).attr('href'));
    return $(this).href() === $(location).attr('href');
  }).addClass('newClass');
```

Where I am doing wrong?

Comment: IMO this type of behavior should be accomplished on on the backend. A better way to do this is through adding body classes or ids.

Comment: Nothing to do with PHP, please don't misuse tags.

Comment: @Cranio, Right but I thought it might be extend to this where I build the navigation. Again, right, not php for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a small, slightly simpler jQuery snippet that should do what you're expecting:

```
$(".topnavigation li a").each(function() {
    if($(this).attr("href") == window.location) {
        $(this).addClass("newClass");
    }
});
```

Demo: [little link](http://goo.gl/4Xkwg).

I hope that helped you!

Answer (score 2):

You can access page url directly with `location.href`, no jquery needed.

To get an attribute of a dom element you can use `attr`

```
 $(this).attr('href')
```

This should work:

```
$(".top_navigation li a").filter(function() {
    return $(this).attr('href') === location.href);
}).addClass('newClass');
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this.

```
$(".top_navigation li a").addClass(function() {
    return this.href === location.href ? "newClass" : "";
});
```